# Set size of checkbox's drawable

Tags: android, checkbox, android-drawable, android-button, android-checkbox

I would like to use custom drawables set as my checkbox drawable I have it defined as follows:

```
heart_button.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/heart_outline" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/heart_full" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/heart_outline" /> <!-- default state -->
</selector>
```

drawables here are just .png files. In layout however I have a following entry:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/heartItemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:button="@drawable/favourite_heart_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/heartCheckBoxDesc"
        android:focusable="false"/>
```

What I want to achieve is to set width and height of that `CheckBox` and has its button drawable scalled to fill it. Now it get cropped (when I use too big .png file) or stays small (when I use lower-resoultion .png).
I believe `dp` units were introduced to prevent various items size depending on phone density. This is way I don't want to just use image with another resolution.

I have tried several ways to achieve what I want - without success. I've tried setting `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`, `android:gravity="center"`, I tried to change `items` in `selector` to introduce `bitmaps` there with `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` attribute. What seemed to work was setting that drawable to `android:background` attribute instead of to `android:button`. But I don't think this a right way (It can make some probles with shadows, elevation, etc. I think).

How do you recommend to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the People Preferred to use android:background like

```
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/check_box"
```

Still if you like to use button then resize your image to 32dp. Because android Material Design suggested to use 32dp for checkbox.

Refer the link. May be it will help you.

[Material Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html)

Comment: How can I achieve shadow effect on such checkbox? Attribute `elevation` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @michalsol  Actually it's an image. So you can't give shadow by code.  But before pasting the  image into draw-able you change it by external Photo Editor